# Logic - Proving or disproving a formula is satisfiable

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I want to find out if the formula $\{p\implies(q\land r),(p\lor r)\implies q,\neg r\}$ is satisfiable. (meanings each clause is satisfiable. there is an $\land$ between the clauses.

The problem is that the first (leftmost) clause is not a Horn clauses, so we can't use Horn's algorithm if I am not mistaken.

Is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite $p \to (q \land r)$ as $\lnot p \lor (q \land r)$ [see [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))] and then apply [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) to get :

> $[\lnot p \lor (q \land r)] \equiv [(\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r)]$.

Thus, we can replace the formula with the couple of [Horn clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause) :

> > $\lnot p \lor q, \lnot p \lor r$.

---

The same approach can be aused with $(p ∨ r) \to q$, and the final result will be :

> $\{ ¬p∨q, ¬p∨r, ¬r∨q, ¬r \}$

that is satisfiable: it is enough to set $p=r=FALSE$.

Comment: Hmm...That helps but we still run into a problem. After splitting the problematic clauses to Horn form I get $\{p \implies q, p \implies r,r \implies q,r \implies F\}$. I don't have a $T$ anywhere. Nothing will be marked.

Comment: We could just set all the literals to $F$ though, that seems to satisfy it.